# AWS Lambda Proxy API not sending querystring to VPCE server

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-5, amazon-vpc

Hi I have problem with the AWS Lambda sending query string to the VPCE server.  My code below:

**AWS LAMBDA CODE**

```js
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    if (event.queryStringParameters !== null) { // check for query string
        console.log('query Strings: ' + querystring.stringify(event.queryStringParameters))
        queries = queries + '?' + querystring.stringify(event.queryStringParameters);
    }

    options = {
        hostname: invokeHostname, // 1234567a.execute-api.ap-something-1.amazonaws.com
        port: 443,
        path: queries, // /api/test/get_something?getId=123
        method: event.httpMethod,
        headers: {}
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        let rawData = '';
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log("chunk: " + chunk)
            rawData += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('response' + rawData);

            response = {
                "statusCode": res.statusCode,
                "body": rawData,
                "isBase64Encoded": false
            };
            console.log(response);
            callback(null, response);
        });
    });
}
```

I am running a ASP.NET Core using .NET 5 for my API and here is my the controller code:

**CONTROLLER ASP.NET**

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("get_something")]
    public IActionResult Test([FromQuery] int getId)
    {
        // do something here.
    }
}
```

Note that it did went through the Controller but it didn't return anything because there is no query string being set.

But when in the VPCE server and I checked the logs it accept as: `https://10.10.3.221/api/test/get_something` only without the query string `getId=123`.  Does anyone has solution on this one?

Comment: Did you check CLoudWatch Logs for any errors from the function?

Comment: I did and it received the correct query string

Answer (score 0):

just fixed the issue, it has something to do with the nginx needs to setup a query string parameter arguments. Hope this will help in the future.
I updated the configuration to something like this:

```
location ~* ^/service/(.*) {
  proxy_pass http://apache/$1$is_args$args;
}
```